# How to build with targets with Google Chromium GN?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chromium, gn

I'm trying to build the executable target for [ChromeDriver](https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver) from source with [GN](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/gn/docs/quick_start.md), which I installed in a directory on my PATH with [Depot Tools](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools), but when I run `gn BUILD.gn` I'm getting this error:

```
gn.py: Could not find checkout in any parent of the current path.
This must be run inside a checkout.
```

I'm not sure if I need to checkout the entire Chromium directory, if I'm not setting this up correctly?

**UPDATE**

I've downloaded a working binary of gn with the help of [gn_tool](https://github.com/cpu-chromium/gn_tool).

I'm still unsure what command I'm supposed to run for "building the chromedriver target", because right now every command I try seems to give me this error:

```
ERROR Can't find source root. I could not find a ".gn" file in the current directory or any parent,and the --root command-line argument was not specified.
```

...even though there is a BUILD.gn file in the directory where I'm running gn...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like some dependencies are missing. You can pull the dependencies by running

```
gclient sync
```

which should download the required dependencies for Chrome driver to compile. Then run the following commands to start compiling Chrome driver:

```
gn gen out/YourBuildFolder
ninja -C out/YourBuildFolder chromedriver
```

The above `gn gen...` command will basically prepare the build folder for the ninja build system to compile by copying the dependencies and preparing necessary files. And `ninja -C...` command will actually start compiling the files

Hope that works. Thanks

Comment: do you know what's up with the buildtools directory? If I don't have it in my directory I can't build my target -- i've added my own target to the source tree.

Comment: my buildtools dir has clang format but the actual compiler is not there, it's in chromium/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang

Comment: i figured most of what I know out through trial and error -- is there  a resource you followed to get your info that you could refer me to?

Comment: Well actually am a Chromium developer but you won't find docs for every thing in the Chromium world. Also gclient sync will download that compiler and other third-party libraries and source code needed for it to compile. So that doesn't necessary mean, it has to be inside buildtools folder. Most of the third-party deps that are downloaded after executing `gclient sync` are stored in `third_party` folder in Chromium. Also you might want to look at `DEPS` file, which include references to repos that will will be downloaded by it

Comment: @ThomasDignan Actually `gclient` is part of `depot_tools` so this page might be helpful to you: https://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/depottools

Comment: Should have mentioned this too: the above `gn gen` command will basically prepare the build folder for the ninja build system to compile by copying the dependencies and necessary files. And `ninja -C` command will actually start compiling the files.

Comment: When "gclient sync" is  done ,you'd better  restart your terminal.

Comment: @Asesh yeah i'm realizing that just wanted to be certain I wasn't missing something easier! thanks very much for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem but figured it out.

When I run gn in depot_tool directory, I got same error message.

[image]

But I run gn in chromium/src directory, gn works!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you don't have a buildtools directory, such as the one in `src/chromium/buildtools` checked in to your git repository.

A cheap way to get this to work outside of chromium's source tree is to copy theirs to your build dir, e.g.:

```
cp -r ~/src/chromium/buildtools myrepo/buildtools
```

and check it in to git

```
cd myrepo
git add buildtools
git commit -m "add buildtools"
```

you should then be able to run `gn gen out` successfully in that repository.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem just now.

According to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools/gn/+/HEAD/docs/standalone.md, '.gn' and other build config files are missing. It seems the project can not be built standalone. Perhaps you should checkout the entire Chromium directory.

Answer (score -1):

path of depot_tool is not setup, try in terminal:

export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools"

in src you have gn as well so that's why code is running.

Answer (score -1):

path of depot_tool is not setup, try in terminal:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools"
```

in src you have gn as well so that's why code is running.

Src folder does not has gn - executable file. This complaint means that the build system cannot find ng.exe(for windows) file is located in "**build_tools**" packet(do not confuse with "**depot_tools**" ). You may set CHROMIUM_BUILDTOOLS_PATH=D:\PROJECTS\Web\ to find it. But you have to download correct version of this.