# How to build own v8 fork

Tags: v8, depottools

I have my own fork of v8 and would like to build it.
However, `gn` and `gclient` keep failing and telling me that I need to be inside a checkout.

```
$> git clone <ownRepository>
$> gn gen out/build
gn.py: Could not find checkout in any parent of the current path.
This must be run inside a checkout.
``

How can I build my own fork? `fetch` does not seem to accept custom repositories.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build with targets with Google Chromium GN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729479/how-to-build-with-targets-with-google-chromium-gn)

Comment: @Mytch no it does not. gclient requires configuration to be run. The accepted solution does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The V8 git repository (or a fork of it) simply doesn't contain everything that's required for building; in particular it misses third-party dependencies and shared build configuration logic. The purpose of the official build tools/workflow is to set all that up. So the easiest path forward for you is probably to get a regular V8 checkout (using `fetch v8`), and then replacing the `v8` directory in there with your own. Make sure that the versions match (at least approximately).

The alternative is to figure out what `fetch v8`, `gclient sync` and `gclient runhooks` do, and doing all of that by hand -- totally possible, as they're all just scripts and entirely open source, but it's a lot of work and not much fun, so I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: I think using `git diff` to generate a patch from when the repo was forked, then using `fetch v8`, then applying the patch works easier. But fundamentally you are (sadly) correct.